# Computing the Length of a Curve on a Cylindrical Surface

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

So we have a cylinder surface $Q$ given by the following parametric equation,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} u \\ \cosh u \\ v\sinh u \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

where, $0\le u\le 1$ and $0\le v\le 1$.

**Question**

I have to find the length of the rim of $Q$.

I am aware that I have to use the line integral, but I do not know how to convert this function into t parametric equation so that I can use the formula.

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equation of the rim can be obtained by setting $v=1$ as

$$\begin{align}
x &= u \\
y &= \cosh u \\
z &= \sinh u
\end{align}$$

which is showed by the $\color{blue}{blue}$ curve below. So the integral for the length of this curve will be

$$\begin{align}
L &= \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{du}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{du}\right)^2}du \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+\sinh^2 u +\cosh^2 u} \,\, du
\end{align}$$

[image]

Comment: @captainavenger96: You are welcome. :) You can up-vote and accept answers. Notice the arrows and the check marks next to each answer. :)

Comment: By setting $v=1 $ do you chose a particular value only.Instead why not put $u=1?$

Comment: @Narasimham: Hi old friend. :) The OP said that it wants to compute the length of a rim of this surface but did not mentioned which rim. I just guessed that it might be the blue curve I showed above.

Comment: Hi, Hallo @HR... then fine, when he knows what he wants.